# как применить этот js ко всем спискам ul?

Tags: javascript

как применить этот js ко всем спискам ul? или к определенным классам? чтобы считались для каждого сначала

```js
  const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
  countnumber = 0; 
  for (child of ul.children){
    countnumber += 1;
    child.style.setProperty('--inc-step', countnumber);
  }
```

```css
    :root {
      --inc-step: 1;
    }

    ul {
      list-style: none; /* прячем маркеры */
      padding-left: 0; 
    }

    ul li{
      opacity: 0.3;
    }

    ul.active li{
      transition: opacity 0.3s linear, top 0.3s linear;
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transition-delay: calc(var(--inc-step)*0.1s);
      -moz-transition-delay: calc(var(--inc-step)*0.1s);
      -ms-transition-delay: calc(var(--inc-step)*0.1s);
      -o-transition-delay: calc(var(--inc-step)*0.1s);
      transition-delay: calc(var(--inc-step)*0.1s);
    }
```

```html
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: const li = document.querySelectorAll('.button');
  countnumbers = 0; 
  for (var i = 0; i < li.length; ++i) {
    countnumbers += 1;
    li[i].style.setProperty('--inc-step', countnumbers);
  }
  сделал так, но он считает не для каждого блока с нуля..

Comment: `const ul = document.querySelectorAll('ul'); [...ul].forEach(function (li) { for (let [index, elem] of [...li.children].entries()){ elem.style.setProperty('--inc-step', index+1); } });` или `const ul = document.querySelectorAll('ul'); [...ul].map(li => [...li.children].map((el, idx) => el.style.setProperty('--inc-step', idx+1)));`, вариантов полно

Comment: InDevX лучший, спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вставил ответ InDevX, все работает спасибо.

```js
const ul = document.querySelectorAll('ul'); [...ul].forEach(function (li) { for (let [index, elem] of [...li.children].entries()){ elem.style.setProperty('--inc-step', index+1); } });
```

```css
    :root {
      --inc-step: 1;
    }

    ul {
      list-style: none; /* прячем маркеры */
      padding-left: 0; 
    }

    ul li{
      opacity: 0.3;
    }

    ul.active li{
      transition: opacity 0.3s linear, top 0.3s linear;
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transition-delay: calc(var(--inc-step)*0.1s);
      -moz-transition-delay: calc(var(--inc-step)*0.1s);
      -ms-transition-delay: calc(var(--inc-step)*0.1s);
      -o-transition-delay: calc(var(--inc-step)*0.1s);
      transition-delay: calc(var(--inc-step)*0.1s);
    }
```

```html
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
  </ul>
```

```js
const ul = document.querySelectorAll('ul'); [...ul].map(li => [...li.children].map((el, idx) => el.style.setProperty('--inc-step', idx+1)));
```

```css
    :root {
      --inc-step: 1;
    }

    ul {
      list-style: none; /* прячем маркеры */
      padding-left: 0; 
    }

    ul li{
      opacity: 0.3;
    }

    ul.active li{
      transition: opacity 0.3s linear, top 0.3s linear;
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transition-delay: calc(var(--inc-step)*0.1s);
      -moz-transition-delay: calc(var(--inc-step)*0.1s);
      -ms-transition-delay: calc(var(--inc-step)*0.1s);
      -o-transition-delay: calc(var(--inc-step)*0.1s);
      transition-delay: calc(var(--inc-step)*0.1s);
    }
```

```html
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
  </ul>
```